# Dropwizard Admin: Change loglevel for all

Tags: java, logging, dropwizard

My config is the standard

```
logging:

  # The default level of all loggers. Can be OFF, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE, or ALL.
  level: INFO

  # Logger-specific levels.
  loggers:

    # Sets the level for 'com.example.app' to DEBUG.
    com.example.app: DEBUG

    # Redirects SQL logs to a separate file
    org.hibernate.SQL:
      level: DEBUG
```

I want to change the default log level for all loggers to `DEBUG`. I've tried the following and nothing works (say admin port is 1234):

```
curl -X POST -d "logger=all&level=DEBUG" localhost:1234/tasks/log-level
curl -X POST -d "level=DEBUG" localhost:1234/tasks/log-level
curl -X POST -d "logger=*&level=DEBUG" localhost:1234/tasks/log-level
```

When I run these with `-vv`, for example for `logger=all`, I see `Configured logging level for all to DEBUG`, but the tailing the log does not change, and is still INFO. Of course, if I change the config and set the top level to `DEBUG`, and restart, I get DEBUG level.

What's the command?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've [checked the source code](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-servlets/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/servlets/tasks/LogConfigurationTask.java) for the `log-level` task and its main logic is implemented like this:

```
for (String loggerName : loggerNames) {
    ((LoggerContext) loggerContext).getLogger(loggerName).setLevel(loggerLevel);
    output.println(String.format("Configured logging level for %s to %s", loggerName, loggerLevel));
    output.flush();
}
```

So the way it's implemented is based on the name for the logger, knowing this I went into the source for `org.slf4j.Logger` interface and found this field:

```
String ROOT_LOGGER_NAME = "ROOT";
```

Doing a `POST` like this solved it for me:

```
curl -X POST -d "logger=ROOT&level=DEBUG" localhost:8081/tasks/log-level
```

Comment: Note that this came in version later than 0.9.3, not sure which exactly. You'd get 404 if it's not in your version.